# Getting total CPU time of a process

Tags: shell

I need to get the total cpu time of a process in android. I am trying to use adb shell top commands, but it gives only cpu usage in terms of percentage.

But I need the total cpu time of the process. I can get this info in my Ubuntu, but I could not find a way to get the TIME+ column in android.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your question restricted to shell use -- or would other options be helpful as well?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which version of Android you are running, but I believe this will work in most modern versions.  The exact location within the settings may change depending on version and device manufacturer.

If you go in to Settings -> Battery and then select an app, you get some or all of  the following details:

- CPU total time in seconds
- Keep awake time in seconds
- Data send
- Data received

I believe these details are valid from the last time the device booted.

Answer (score 0):

This little shell script I just wrote should work. It parses `/proc/<PID>/stat`.

```
#!/system/bin/sh

if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
    echo "Please provide a PID"
    exit 0
fi

pid=$1
stat=/proc/${pid}/stat
line=$(sed 's|.*) ||' $stat)
utime=$(echo $line | awk '{print $12}')
stime=$(echo $line | awk '{print $13}')
cputime=$((10 * $stime + $utime))
echo $cputime # milliseconds
```

Comment: I am a noob in adb, so help me how to run this. I used cat > cpuinfo to create this as a file but can't run it because permission denied. chmod u+x cpuinfo tells me Operation not permitted. Out of luck on non-rooted phone?